# UITextInteractionAssistant Error _forgetDependentConstraint

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, ios6

I encounter a serious bug which crashes my app and google does not give any hint. I am wondering if anyone here can help. I use PTPasscodeViewController from [here](https://github.com/lashad/PTPasscodeViewController). I have been using it since 2010. I am updating my app for ios6 and iphone 5. I start changing my app to ARC but left PTPasscodeViewController as -fno-obj-arc.

However, everytime I access the passcode view page, my simulator keeps crashing with very little error message in the console. But one time, I get this message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextInteractionAssistant
>   _forgetDependentConstraint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa554500'

It is something that I don't understand. If I put a breakpoint the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

I can actually set the passcode. Every time I enter a value in the text field, it triggers the method and I have to continue the breakpoint 4 times but it works.

If you have any advice or pointers, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I disabled the auto layout from the view and it worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't reproduce it since I've started from scratch again but the next time I encounter it, I'll definitely try out your suggestion